# How exactly does Percentage get reference height at top or bottom etc. property?

Tags: html, css

I could not understand the point of percentage.

In this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top#Summary

it says: "refer to the height of the containing block"

But what does it mean by "containing block"?

I tried some code but I still don't get it.

Suppose that we have this code :

```
<div class="block1">
<p>This will be my blog I will use</p>
</div>
```

and in css

```
.block1{
top=50%; <!--now if we use this "%" Where to get reference?-->
height:100px;
}
```

I thought that it might be a reference to html size.

if I change it, my top edge changes automatically because I changed the reference height but html was not! (may be I can not change it)

So where does percentage(%) get gets its reference value from?

Comment: Just FYI, CSS uses `:` for assignment not `=` (perhaps a typo). Also CSS comments are made using `/**/` not `<!-- -->` (those are html comments)

Comment: yea I think I'm a little confused :) thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your CSS code is wrong.

```
top=50%;
```

should be

```
top: 50%;
```

Your HTML document is typically structured like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="block1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

So since `.block1` is placed inside `<body></body>`, then `<body></body>` becomes the "containing block", since elements are by default treated as blocks (`display:block)`;

But the effect of `top: 50%` depends on other things too, like the property `position:` and its value `absolute/relative/fixed/etc;` of `.block1`.

`absolute` will position the element independently from everything else with one exception that I will talk about below.

`relative` will position the element relative to all of the other elements, which, again, are by default `display: block` and `position: relative`, which means if you had an HTML document like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="block1" class="block"></div>
  <div id="b2"        class="block"></div>
  <div id="b3"        class="block"></div>
</body>
</html>

.block {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Then it would display the document like :

```
____________________top of page___________________________
| [[.block1]]----displayed as block, takes up whole row---|
| [[#b2    ]]----displayed as block, takes up whole row---|
| [[#b3    ]]----displayed as block, takes up whole row---|
| next element would be added here                        |
| and then here                                           |
| and then below again                                    |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
```

The document behaves kind of like upside-down Tetris. Every element with default settings is placed at the top of the page, and then moves/stacks in a downward direction as more and more elements are added. Since elements by default are `display: block`, this means that an element will take up the entire width of the containing element, even if it's only half the width, so that the next element will be placed below it.

Additionally, if the parent element's `position` is set to `relative`, and the child is set to `absolute`, then the child will be positioned in relation to the parent. So if the child had `position: absolute; top: 50%;`, it would **not** position itself independently but rather `50%` from the top of the parent element.

```
 _____________________0% of document/body_______
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|       ____parent - 0%_____                    |
|      |                    |                   |
|      |                    |                   |
|      |     ___________    |                   |
|      |    |           |   |                   |
|      |    |child - 50%|   |                   |
|      |    |___________|   |                   |
|      |                    |                   |
|      |                    |                   |
|      |_______100%_________|                   |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|_____100% of document/body_____________________|
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Emrah awesome! glad I could help. here are some links, which might be helpful: [display,](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) [position,](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) and [top](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It references its value from its parent.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LcqjabpL/)

HTML

```
<div class="parentBox">
  <div class="childBox"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parentBox{
  position:absolute;
  top:10%
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background:red;
}
.childBox{
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background:blue;
}
```

Although parentBox and childBox has the same values for width and height, you could notice that they are not the same, since childBox is contained within parentBox (it is the child of parentBox) then it explicitly states to take 50% of the width of parentBox and apply it to itself- same goes for its height.

UPDATE:
Stuffs like the top property works in the same manner, basically all that uses the percent(%) value.

Comment: i think OP is asking about the `top` CSS style and how it relates to `height` not just how `height` and `width` work

Comment: Updated it to make it more clear, but I think he's just asking about how the percentage value works.

Comment: thank you for answers. now I understand clearly this section